# Is it ok to pass Stripe Client Secret to the view using query parameters in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, stripe-payments

The client-secret from the payment intent display in the url with query parameters (According to the current implementation, this is a redirect url with query parameters) Is this fine? Any way to pass the client secret securely to the scripts in MVC view?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.